# AWS Java hosting w/ GoDaddy domain

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, ssl, web-hosting

Thank you to Stack Overflow for all of the help in the past. I was hoping to ask a few questions about getting AWS Java web application hosting to work with a GoDaddy domain, to see if what I'm trying to do is possible.

I have firststepfreedom.co purchased from GoDaddy. I am trying to develop and deploy a Java Web Application using Hibernate(MySQL)/Spring MVC. Ideally, I need:

- Masking that still allows me to have firststepfreedom.co/custom/mapping etc.
- Java compatibility. This is a requirement.
- SSL certificate so I can use Maps API and get rid of that damn "not secure" warning in chrome.
- Database configuration through AWS for MySQL.

Currently, I have my site hosting on an elastic beanstalk server, with GoDaddy rerouting (w/ masking) to the elastic beanstalk. This makes my SSL certs not work in expected ways, and it removes the ability to bookmark specific pages.

Is there a way to configure through AWS what it is I'm looking for here? Do I need to switch to route53 or EC2 in some way?

Comment: why go with godaddy when you have domain services offered by aws route 53 and aws ssl certificate manager?  https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/

Comment: Because I purchased the domain from GoDaddy after being told by GoDaddy staff that I could host java apps there. As it turns out they don't. I'm pigeon-holed on the domain name because everything else is taken, and now it's owned by GoDaddy. With time constraints at work, I don't have time to screw around with down time so I just need it to work with what I have. Is it possible?

Comment: have you purchased ssl certificate for your domain in godaddy?

Comment: You can migrate to route53 by updating the name servers to AWS after you create a public rout53 domain it will give you a set of name servers to use. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/domain-transfer-to-route-53.html

Comment: @strongjz Does this transfer the domain from GoDaddy or dies this do something else? does this still allow me to create email accounts for the site?

Comment: No it doesn't change who the registar is, it just changes the DNS authoritative name servers for the domain. You'll have to add the MX records to point to GoDaddy so you can still create email address thru their services.

Comment: Okay, so I created a hosted zone and created a CNAME record set that points www.firststepfreedom.co to my elastic beanstalk and a CNAME that points from *.firststepfreedom.co to www.firststepfreedom.co.

As well, I added the nameservers provided by Route 53 to my DNS setting sin the goDaddy panel. Now I get this error message when I go to the site: https://gyazo.com/8c9f12335a5a0e717e3186d798c20d42

Is this normal, to have a couple hours of downtime after a change like this? Have I done something wrong?